# How do you know/look up what themes and styles are available with androidx.appcompat?

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I used tools:replace="android:theme" to replace theme of a 3rd-party activity, so it shows ActionBar with back button icon and text as I wanted.

With try and errors, I found out that I was able to apply android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar" that comes from androidx.appcompat. However, I got this style name only by digging into a random search result of appcompat source:
[https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-release/appcompat/res/values/](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-release/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml)

My question is: is there an official documentation about the resources available in androidx.appcompat?

Answer (score 0):

In the docs of https://developer.android.com/ , you can find the official documentation of the resources available in `androidx.appcompat`. If you want, you can start here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/package-summary?hl=en